# Rabbitmq Stomp plugin stops accepting connections

Tags: tomcat, rabbitmq, stomp, spring-websocket

I have a RabbitMq server (3.5.1) with Embedded Rabbit Stomp Adapter. Stomp protocol is exposed through 61613 port. 
RabbitMq acts as a broker for Websocket connections on Tomcat server (8.0.22). 
After about 12000 users connected to the socket which means there about 12000 TCP connections established between Tomcat and RabbitMq servers I get the following error on Tomcat:

```
[eactor-tcp-io-4] ERROR o.s.m.s.s.StompBrokerRelayMess 
TCP connection failure in session ic15zto4: 
failed to establish TCP connection in session
ic15zto4io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException:
connection timed out: /192.168.28.32:61613
```

It looks like the RabbitMq Stomp Adapter stops accepting new connections.
The metrics on the RabbitMq (open files, file descriptors, memory, etc.) are all right. There are no errors in RabbitMq logs either.

What can be the cause of such behaviour?

Comment: Do you have some error on rmq logs?

Comment: RabbitMQ log looks all right.

Comment: what about the file descriptors settings for your Tomcat server?